# Select rows based on a window of 10 days with an offset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timestamp

I have a table with 3 columns including a timestamp called `startson`:

> events ( **eventid** number, **name** varchar2, **startson** timestamp )

I have a variable that is a number which is an offset that says what the `startson` boundry should be in my where clause.

For example:

```
if my_var = 0 (select events that started in the last 10 days)
if my_var = 1 (select events that started 20 days ago up until 10 days ago)
if my_var = 2 (select events that started 30 days ago up until 20 days ago)
if my_var = 3 (select events that started 40 days ago up until 30 days ago)
.. and so on
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
select * 
from events 
where startson >= (sysdate-(10*my_var)) 
and startson <= (sysdate-(10*my_var+10)) 
order by startson asc
```

This doesn't return any rows even though I know there are hundreds of rows with some starting in the last 10 days.

Comment: When you say "started in the last 10 days", do you mean exactly 10 days ago from "this very second", or 10 days before the "start of today"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a minus sign after your multiplication sign.

```
(sysdate-(10*-my_var))
```

In your case you will end up with something like

```
(sysdate -(10 * -1)) that will give you (sysdate + 10 days)
```

Maybe you should have something more like

```
(sysdate-(10*my_var))
```

And you should invert the  "<=" and ">=" conditions for

```
where startson <= (sysdate-(10*my_var)) 
and startson >= (sysdate-(10*my_var+10))
```

Comment: Yep, that'd do it, hard to be greater than a future date _and_ less than one in the past.

Comment: This still returns no rows (tested with my_var=0). thanks for trying though.

Comment: @ServerBloke see my edit.  Somebody have add the comment but deleted it.  So I add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic formula if I understood the problem correctly:

```
-- between last 10 days --
WHERE startson BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE) AND (trunc(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' DAY)
```

To get all intervals in a single select:

```
SELECT start_date, ten_days_ago, twenty_days_ago, thirty_days_ago, fourty_days_ago
  FROM
(
 SELECT trunc(SYSDATE) start_date
     , (trunc(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '10' DAY) ten_days_ago
     , (trunc(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '20' DAY) twenty_days_ago
     , (trunc(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '30' DAY) thirty_days_ago
     , (trunc(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '40' DAY) fourty_days_ago
  FROM dual
)
--WHERE your_column BETWEEN twenty_days_ago AND ten_days_ago
/
```